# Does msmq have an interface?

Tags: windows-server-2008, msmq

I've used MSMQ on a Windows 2003 server before and noticed I could monitor the public and private queues.

Does anyone know if you can do this on Windows 2008 server?  If so, how do I access it because I've search and can't find a way to monitor this. At least not from a GUI interface like before.

Answer (score 1):

Has Message Queuing been installed on the machine?

Server Manager | Features | Add Features

Comment: Yes, it's installed already using Features > Message Queuing.

Comment: Yes it's been install already.  I used the Features area to install it as well as made sure the service is running.  I just want to know if it has an interface/GUI like windows 2003 does.  In win2003 it's under Computer management > Services and Applications > Message Queuing

Comment: Never mind I found it.  I had to go to mmc > Add the computer management snap-in and it was under services and applications.

Comment: @Michael: Suggest you add that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO MSMQ is the MS tool with the worst support for end user as it is much more intended to be used programmatically. I used QueueExplorer for management:

http://www.cogin.com/mq/qefeatures.php

Management can be also done using PowerShell (both interactive and script, but on command-line on course)

Regards, D